# Can I sign my emails with both S/MIME and PGP/GPG?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature, smime

And if it possible, is there any benefit from doing so in one order or the other?

```
signWithSMIME(signWithPGP(message))
```

versus

```
signWithPGP(signWithSMIME(message))
```

Also, are there any reason not to sign with both?

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not really see the benefit, in principle it possible using the first approach if you sign first with PGP/INLINE (aka PGP traditional). The second option will not work since signing with PGP after signing with S/MIME will break the S/MIME message, i.e., the S/MIME message will no longer be a valid S/MIME message.